Are sets unary relations, and are unary relations sets?
On page 57 of Axiomatic Set Theory by Patrick Suppes, he defines a binary relation as a set of ordered pairs.
Definition 1. A is a binary relation iff
∀x[if x∈A then ∃y∃z[x=(y,z)]]
He defines an ordered pair as follows.
(x,y) = {{x}, {x,y}}
This definition is due to Kuratowski [1921].
My question is, does the following definition make sense?
Definition 2. A is a set iff
∀x[if x∈A then ∃y[x= (y)]]
In other words, is a set a unary relation?

EDIT-
Since posting this, I've found a problem.
Individuals don't contain elements.  So, if unary relations are sets then
Definition 2. Albert Einstein is a set iff
∀x[if x∈ Albert Einstein then ∃y[x= (y)]]
The antecedent is false, so the conditional is true, therefore Albert Einstein is a set.  Thus I'm forced to conclude unary relations aren't always sets.

To answer my question you obviously must give a meaning to a 1-tuple (y), but I don't know what that is.
On page 19, Suppes defines 'set' as follows.
Definition 1. y is a set iff ∃x[x∈y ∨ y=∅]
So, I presume, to answer my question you must show Definitions 1&2 are equivalent.
I found the following at Wikipedia.
Unary
Unary (1-ary) relations can be viewed as a collection of members (such as the collection of Nobel laureates) having some property (such as that of having been awarded the Nobel prize).
Every nullary function is a unary relation.
Based on this Wikipedia statement, it seems that a non-empty set is a unary relation. So is the empty set also a unary relation?

Yes, a set is a unary relation. We let (x) just be defined to be x

In set theory there are only sets. Relations and functions are sets.

Your proposal does not work. A relation is a set of pairs. A pair is a set of sets. Thus, you cannot define a set with relations and pairs.

@MichaelCarey, yes I was thinking that very same thing.  So, if for any x[if x is in A then x denotes something] then A  denotes a set, and conversely.  I'm not sure I see the connection to Suppes' definition of 'set' though.

@MauroALLEGRANZA A unary relation is quite a strange piece of terminology because it is just a subset of a set, and so is not necessarily a relation. But it can be defined, and any set is a unary relation.

You can certainly define a unary relation as a set, and if you define it right, then all sets are unary relations. However, you can also define relations differently. For example, you can create a theory of n-ary relations having no foundation other than axioms of how they behave. If you define them the right way, you can arrange an isomorphism between 1-ary relations and sets, but that doesn't necessarily make them the same thing.
Also, some authors define relations as being intensional. Sets are extensional, so if you defined 1-ary relations as intensional objects, then they are not directly comparable to sets. To say that something is extensional to say that something like the axiom of extensionality is true for them. For sets, it would be something like: if S1 and S2 are sets, and everything that is in S1 is in S2 and everything that is in S2 is in S1, then S1 and S2 are the same set. Contrast this with a property which is intensional. So, for example, the set of all odd numbers between 2 and 8 is the same as the set of all prime numbers between 3 and 10 (I'm using "between" inclusively in this example). But the properties "odd number between 2 and 8" is not the same as the property "prime number between 3 and 10". One property refers to 2, 8, and odd numbers, the other property refers to 3, 10, and prime numbers. They are distinct properties even though the exact same numbers satisfy the two properties. So properties are intensional; there is nothing analogous to the axiom of extensionality that applies to them.

What does it mean to say a relation can be intensional,.  What does mean to say a set is extensional.

@leepappas, I've expanded my answer to explain.

are properties generally intensional? I was thinking of defining all predicate constants as denoting n-ary relations, and defining all n-ary relations as sets. In that conception a property is a 1-ary relation, hence a SET. Or are you using a different meaning of the term 'property'?  In the case of 0-ary relations, I was thinking of treating them as propositions.  A proposition isn't a set, so they are an exception to this scheme.

@leepappas, it's traditional to view properties as intensional, but as long as you are clear in defining your terms, you won't cause any confusion by saying they are extensional. However, you may be asked to explain what's the difference between an extensional property and a set because they seem to be the same thing.


"Are sets unary relations, and are unary relations sets?"

The point mentioned by David about viewing a predicate (one-place relation) as intensional and a set as extensional, is a valid point.  The idea that one need not necessarily convert intensionality to extensionality is a key insight of Simpson's investigations into second-order arithmetic (more precisely, "two-tiered first-order") that are quite popular today (in the sense that there is a lot of work being done in that area).  Even in the context of set-theoretic foundations (stronger than second-order arithmetic), there is work done in systems where, while one can always express a set by a predicate, the opposite is not true: there are predicates which do not specify a set.  An example is the Internal Set Theory of Nelson and its recent variants.
